# formArray - Cannot find path to array of arrays

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

My FormGroup has this structure

```
asyncValidator: null
     controls: Object
       arr: FormArray
       asyncValidator: null
         controls: Array[6]
           0: FormGroup
           asyncValidator: null
           controls: Object
             name: FormControl
             pay: FormControl
             scores: FormArray
             asyncValidator: null
              controls: Array[3]
                0: FormControl
                   ...
                   value: 1
                   ...
                1: FormControl
                2: FormControl
                errors: null
                   ...
```

What is the proper html syntax to access the FormControl and values of the "scores" FormArray

I've tried many combinations of the html below without success

```
{{myForm.value | json}}
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div formArrayName="arr" *ngFor="let a of myForm.get('arr').controls; let i = index">
    <div [formGroupName]="i" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
      <input type="text" name="name" formControlName="name">
      <label for="pay">Pay:</label>
      <input type="text" name="pay" formControlName="pay">
      <div [formArrayName]="scores">
      <div  *ngFor="let _ of scores.controls; let g = index"> 
      <input type="text"  [formControlName]="g">
    </div></div></div></div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Name and pay are properly returned.

Error reported is

```
ERROR
Error: Cannot find control with path: 'arr -> 0 -> '
ERROR
Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'controls')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below html:

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div formArrayName="arr" *ngFor="let a of arr.controls; let i = index">  <!-- arr getter is called -->
    <div [formGroupName]="i" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
      <input type="text" name="name" formControlName="name">
      <label for="pay">Pay:</label>
      <input type="text" name="pay" formControlName="pay">
      <div formArrayName="scores"> <!-- Property binding is not required  -->
      <div  *ngFor="let _ of scores(i).controls; let g = index"> <!-- inner FormArray is retrieved based on index -->
      <input type="text"  [formControlName]="g">
    </div></div></div></div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and define appropriate getter and method to get hold of the FormArray as:

```ts
// returns the outer FormArray
get arr(): FormArray {
  return this.myForm.get('arr') as FormArray;
}

// returns the inner FormArray based on the index 
scores(index: number): FormArray {
  return this.arr.at(index).get('scores') as FormArray;
}
```

Comment: you can use also `this.arr.at(index).get('scores') as FormArray` to get the scores array

Comment: Thanks @Eliseo, edited the answer as per your comment :)

Comment: Works perfectly.  I could tell that the error report was saying that the scores index was a string, but I couldn't figure out how to get that property name.